# Merge multiple records in single row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by, null

I am trying to get two separate records to display on a single line, but keep getting multiple lines with nulls.  I thought that if I grouped by Test_Date, I'd be able to get a single row for each test date, with the scores on a single line, but as you can see, that is not working out for me.

How can I combine the two rows into a single row that presents the Mathematics score next to the reading score?

```
SELECT st.test_date, t.name, decode(ts.name,'Mathematics', sts.numscore) as Mathematics,
decode(ts.name, 'Reading', sts.numscore) as Reading
FROM studenttestscore sts
     JOIN studenttest st ON sts.studenttestid = st.id
     JOIN testscore ts ON sts.testscoreid = ts.id
     JOIN test t on ts.testid = t.id
     JOIN students s ON s.id = st.studentid
WHERE t.id IN (601, 602, 603)
     AND s.student_number = '108156'
GROUP BY st.test_date, t.name, 
         decode(ts.name,'Mathematics', sts.numscore),
         decode(ts.name, 'Reading', sts.numscore)
ORDER BY st.test_date

--- CURRENT OUTPUT ---

Test_Date    Name        Mathematics    Reading
29-AUG-13    MAP FALL            227     (null)
29-AUG-13    MAP FALL         (null)        213
22-JAN-14    MAP WINTER          231     (null)
22-JAN-14    MAP WINTER       (null)        229
05-MAY-14    MAP SPRING          238     (null)
05-MAY-14    MAP SPRING       (null)        233

--- DESIRED OUTPUT ---

Test_Date    Name        Mathematics    Reading
29-AUG-13    MAP FALL            227        213
22-JAN-14    MAP WINTER          231        229
05-MAY-14    MAP SPRING          238        233
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want one name for the date and the name, so only include them in the `GROUP BY`.  Use aggregation functions for the rest:

```
SELECT st.test_date, t.name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ts.name = 'Mathematics' THEN sts.numscore END) as Mathematics,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ts.name = 'Reading' THEN sts.numscore END) as Reading
FROM studenttestscore sts JOIN
     studenttest st
     ON sts.studenttestid = st.id JOIN
     testscore ts
     ON sts.testscoreid = ts.id JOIN
     test t
     ON ts.testid = t.id JOIN
     students s
     ON s.id = st.studentid
WHERE t.id IN (601, 602, 603) AND s.student_number = '108156'
GROUP BY st.test_date, t.name, 
ORDER BY st.test_date;
```

I also replaced `decode()` with `CASE`, which is the ANSI standard form for expressing conditions in expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Aggergate `MAX()` and group by name and testdate to get desired result

<kbd>[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e5eba/3)</kbd>

```
select t.test_date, 
        t.name, max(Mathematics) as Mathematics,
        max(Reading) as Reading 
from t
GROUP BY t.test_date, t.name
ORDER BY t.test_date;
```